# UWP Windows 10 Printing Exception

Tags: c#, printing, uwp, windows-10-universal

Several months back I wanted to add printing to my application. I was able to due so by following the UWP Printing sample from Microsoft's Github. However, when I tested it again a few weeks ago I started to get this exception: System.AccessViolationException. the exception occurs in the following method:

```
protected virtual void GetPrintPreviewPage(object sender, GetPreviewPageEventArgs e)
{
    PrintDocument printDoc = (PrintDocument)sender;
    printDoc.SetPreviewPage(e.PageNumber, printPreviewPages[e.PageNumber - 1]); //exception occurs here
}
//e.PageNumber = 1
//sender is a Windows.UI.Xaml.Printing.PrintDocument
//printDoc is a Windows.UI.Xaml.Pringint.PrintDocument
```

Exception Details:

System.AccessViolationException: 'Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.'

I have yet to find any sources about this type of exception while printing. If anyone has an idea of what is happening I would be grateful for your help.

Comment: Have you edited the UWP Printing sample? If not, have you update your device edition? Could you tell us more details about your device and develop environment?

Comment: I am Targeting the Anniversary Edition of Windows 10. As a side note, I just downloaded the latest print sample from Github. When I run the print sample that Microsoft publishes (no changes) I still have the same exception occurring. I am running the latest version of windows 10 and I am using Visual Studio 2017.